# cifs: mount error(66): Object is remote

Tags: linux, samba, fedora, mount, cifs

I'm trying to mount a remote Windows share directory on a Linux server.  I can access the Windows share from other Windows boxes without any difficulty - but I need to be able to access it from the Linux server as well.

The command that I'm using is:

```
$ mount -t cifs //172.16.0.20/share . -o user=USERNAME
Password:
mount error(66): Object is remote
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g.man mount.cifs)
```

This error seems pretty generic and the man pages aren't very helpful. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 2):

Googling around seems to associate this error with Distributed File Systems. It would seem that the cifs module in the kernel can't handle DFS shares, and throws this error when it runs into one. That said, smbclient can handle DFS shares.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure but UNC paths use the backslash not the forward slash that you are using, might be the issue.